# How should I show that all natural numbers bigger than 17 can be shown as 3m +10K?

Tags: discrete-mathematics

Suppose that a bank machine can dispense money in either 3\$ or 10\$ bills. Show that any amount over 17\$ could be dispensed with combinations of only the 3\$ or the 10\$ bills

Comment: Welcome to MSE. Your question is phrased as an isolated problem, without any further information or context. This does not match [many users' quality standards](http://goo.gl/mLWc8), so it may attract downvotes, or closed. To prevent that, please [edit] the question. [This](http://goo.gl/PlJyVQ) will help you recognise and resolve the issues. Concretely: please provide context, and include your work and thoughts on the problem. These changes can help in formulating more appropriate answers.

Comment: See Frobenius Coin Problem https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem

Comment: Write out expressions for $18,19,20.$  Any number larger than that can be found by adding a multiple of $3$ to one of those expressions.

Comment: Nitpick.  The question in the title is obviously wrong.  18 isn't a multiple of 10, 19 isn't a mulitple of either, 20 isn't a multiple of 3, 21 isn't a multiple of 10, etc.  Why not simply so "are a sum of a multiple of 3 and a multiple of 10"?

Comment: @fleablood yes, it's true. The question is wrongly stated. I think Sara_47 meant : for all $n \in \mathbb{N}, n>17$ there exist $k_1,k_2 \in \mathbb{N}$ such that $n = 3k_1 + 10k_2$

Comment: It's certain that she meant "How $\color{gray}{\text{should}}$ **can**  I show that all $\color{gray}{\text{numbers}}$ **integers** $\color{grey}{\text{bigger}}$ **larger** than 17 can be $\color{red}{\text{shown as multiples of 3 and 10}}$ **expressed as the sum of a positive multiple of 3 and a positive multiple of 10**?"  But I am nitpicky that "shown as multiples of 3 and 10" means something very different than what she intended.  (Although the grey stuff is just me putting on my overly fussy editor hat.)

Comment: Things for the OP to think about.  If $N = 10k + 3m$ then $N+3= 10k + 3(m+1)$.  (Also, maybe but not really necessary, if  $N=10k + 3m$ and $m\ge 3$ then $N+1= 10(k+1) + 3(m-3)$.  And if $N=10k + 3m$ and $k\ge 2$ then $N+1 = 10(k-2) + 3(m + 7)$).

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Given a number $n \in \mathbb{N}$, then one of the following can happen:
$n \equiv 0 \ (mod 3)$
$n \equiv 1 \ (mod 3)$
$n \equiv 2 \ (mod 3)$
i.e. $n$ can be of the form $3k$ or $3k+1$ or $3k + 2$.
If $n$ is a multiple of $3$ then you can write $$n = 3k + 10 \cdot 0$$
If $n = 3k + 1$ then
$$n = 3k +1 = 3k + 10-9 = 3(k-3) + 10$$
Notice that $k$ is at least $6$ since $n >17$.
If $n = 3k +2$ then
$$n = 3k+2 = 3k+20-18 = 3(k-6) + 10 \cdot 2$$
Notice that $k-6$ is non-negative since $n > 17$.

Answer (score 0):

For any $a,b$, such that $g.c.d(a,b)=1$, all numbers greater than $ab-a-b$ can be written in the form $na+mb$. This is is the Fröbenius problem, you can find more information here:
[The Frobenius Coin Problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/654697/the-frobenius-coin-problem)