# Given two positive integers a , b , $gcd(a, b) = 1$, prove for any integer n > ab-a-b there exist integers $x, y\ge0$ such that $ax+by = n$

Tags: elementary-number-theory, linear-diophantine-equations

Given two positive integers $a$, $b$  with $\gcd(a, b) = 1$, prove that for any integer $n > ab-a-b$  there exist non-negative integers $x$, $y$ such that $ax+by = n$

We can prove that for $c = ab-a-b$, there isn't such non-negative $x$ and $y$ with $ax+by = c$

Beacuse $gcd(a, b) = 1$, there exist $x_0$ and $y_0$ with $ax_0+by_0 = 1$.

For $n>c$, we have $anx_0+bny_0 = n$

Because $gcd(a, b) = 1$, so $a(nx_0-kb)+b(ny_0+ka) = n$, $\;k \in \mathbb{Z}$

I wander how to prove that there exists $k$ such that:
\begin{align}
nx_0 - kb &\geq 0 \\
ny_0 + ka &\ge 0
\end{align}

Comment: Cf. [$n=2$ case of the Frobenius coin problem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem#n_=_2).

Comment: Perhaps this can help https://math.stackexchange.com/a/654734/68092

Comment: @AnuragA Thank you  so much :D