# When You Have Three Chicken McNugget Container Sizes

Tags: elementary-number-theory

if Chicken McNuggets are sold in containers of sizes $x$ and $y$ where $\gcd x,y = 1$ [then it is known that the maximum number of nuggets that it is impossible to buy exactly](http://artofproblemsolving.com/wiki/index.php?title=Chicken_McNugget_Theorem) is $xy - x - y$.

but what if Chicken McNuggets are sold in containers of sizes $x$, $y$, and $z$? with $\gcd x, y = 1$ and $\gcd x,z = 1$ and $\gcd y, z =1 $? im gonna say its probably something like $xyz - xy - xz - yz + x + y + z$ but thats probably completely wrong lol

for two nugget boxes it's the same as $(x-1)(y-1) -1$ so maybe for $3$ nugget boxes it will be $(x-1)(y-1)(z-1)-1$? so that's $xyz - xy - xz - yz + x + y + z$

Comment: it is known that there is no general "formula" for three or more items; at the same time, given three specific numbers, it is easy enough to find your bound,   https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Coin_problem  Note a special case, "However, upon some special scenarios, the Frobenius number can be calculated"

Comment: @WillJagy Cool. Why is it so easy for two containers and so hard for three?

Comment: @WillJagy thanks for the link it has a lot of info ... I didn't know it was that famous of a topic

Comment: Does this answer your question? [Extensions of Chicken Nugget Theorem](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/3202477/extensions-of-chicken-nugget-theorem)

Comment: "Chicken Nugget Theorem" haha

Comment: McNuggets are sold in sizes of 4, 6, 10, 20 and 50. Therefore this problem is bunk.

Answer (score 0):

The original question is about boxes of 6, 9 and 20 nuggets. So, all we need to do is trying to write the smallest possible number as a sum in terms of 9 and 20 for each x ≡ y mod 6 where y : {0,1,2,3,4,5}.

x ≡ 0 mod 6 (we have 6, which is an exception for not using 9 nor 20.)

x ≡ 1 mod 6 (we have 49 as the smallest : 20+20+9. The next term congruent to 1 mod 6 is of course 49+6=55 and so on.)

x ≡ 2 mod 6 (we have 20 as the smallest. The next term is 20+6=26 and so on.)

x ≡ 3 mod 6 (we have 9 as the smallest. The next term is 9+6=15 and so on.)

x ≡ 4 mod 6 (we have 40 as the smallest : 20+20. The next term is 40+6=46.)

x ≡ 5 mod 6 (we have 29 as the smallest : 20+9. The next term is 29+6=35.)

The Frobenius number is 49(the largest on the list)-6 = 43

It is the easiest way of solving this problem.

Comment: Why do you subtract 6 from 49?

Comment: @Shub: 49 is the smallest number equivalent to 1 mod 6 that can be made, therefore the one below it (43) can't.