# Applications of homological algebra in combinatorics

Tags: combinatorics, reference-request, homological-algebra

I have started learning homological algebra recently. It looks like the most abstract subject I've seen so far. The most concrete one is without doubts is combinatorics. So I have very specific reference request -

Can you provide a reference to a book/research paper/whatever that illustrates how abstract homological tools allow to compute something concrete/finite/nontrivial or at least prove it exists.

Thanks a lot for your time!

Comment: How about Richard Stanley's *Combinatorics and Commutative Algebra*?

Comment: Interesting, let me check.

Comment: You can use sheaf cohomology of algebraic varieties (which I think qualifies as homological algebra) to prove the existence of the Frobenius number for subsemigroups $S$ of $\mathbf{N}$; see [one of my answers](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924076/116766). By being more careful, you can even bound the Frobenius number in this way; this is a theorem due to [L'vovsky](http://dx.doi.org/10.1007/BF01445273). Of course, there are other bounds available, but L'vovsky's holds for arbitrary $S$.

Comment: Takumi Murayama, thanks for the comment. The world is so small, I saw L'vovsky last week. I will ask him about this for sure :)

Answer (score 5):

This isn't exactly an application of bare homological algebra, but it does involve cohomology: the [hard Lefschetz theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Lefschetz_hyperplane_theorem#Hard_Lefschetz_theorem) in algebraic geometry implies that the sequences of even and odd [Betti numbers](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Betti_number) of a smooth projective variety over $\mathbb{C}$ are both unimodal, meaning that they first increase and then decrease. A simple example is a product of $n$ copies of the complex projective line $\mathbb{CP}^1$; here the even Betti numbers are binomial coefficients ${n \choose k}$.

A more interesting example is the [Grassmannian](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Grassmannian) $\text{Gr}_d(\mathbb{C}^n)$, whose even Betti numbers count the number of partitions fitting into a $d \times (n-d)$ box. No purely combinatorial proof that this sequence is unimodal is known (edit: it seems my information is out of date! See [this survey by Zeilberger](https://www.maa.org/sites/default/files/pdf/upload_library/22/Ford/Zeilberger590-602.pdf) of the result, which is due to O'Hara). See [this survey by Stanley](http://www.mathunion.org/ICM/ICM1983.1/Main/icm1983.1.0447.0464.ocr.pdf) for more.

Comment: There is a purely combinatorial proof by Kathy O'Hara.

Comment: Cool; thanks for the update!

Answer (score 1):

In this paper [Power series representing Posets](https://arxiv.org/abs/2105.06633) the problem of counting in how many ways can you label a Poset (while preserving the order) is solved for a family of Posets called Wixárika Posets (they look like Wixárika collars). The main results are proven using homological algebra ideas. As a consequence several combinatorial identities were discovered (we checked on books of identities and we coulnd't find them).