# The Chicken McNuggets Problem, as it relates to ideals and Grobner bases in algebraic geometry

Tags: algebraic-geometry

I am studying a course in algebraic geometry. I was given an introduction to the Chicken McNuggets problem, and I've been asked to discuss it within the algebraic geometry principals of ideals and Grobner bases.

I am asking for some references and books so I could understand this problem and write on it. I would like some help, please.

Comment: Maybe I could help if you had something more specific in mind. For example, what result concerning the "Chicken McNuggets" problem would you like to present? This problem is also known as the Diophantine Frobenius problem, about which [Ramírez Alfonsín](https://doi.org/10.1093/acprof:oso/9780198568209.001.0001) has written a book. I don't recall him using any Gröbner basis techniques, though, and [my own knowledge on the problem](https://math.stackexchange.com/a/1924076/116766) is from the perspective of algebraic geometry and sheaf cohomology.